# PowerShell Parse Non-Standard JSON

Tags: json, powershell, parsing

I have some JSON like config files that I need to parse...  They look something like

```
{
    "_Comment":"This is not valid, but required or it breaks the program",
    "_Comment":"If there is only one of these, standard Converters work",
    "_Comment":"But, there are multiple of these lines",
    "Name":"Some Body",
    "Address1":"123 Name of Street",
    "City":"Some Town",
    "ST":"AZ",
    "Zip":"01234-5678",
    "ItemCount": 101
}
```

If I strip out the "_Comment" and "_Comments" lines, it parses correctly, but if I save it and don't put the "_Comment" and "_Comments" lines back, it breaks the application that uses the info.

Any suggestions on how I can strip out and put back those _Comment and Comments lines, or should I take a different approach?

This project requires that I use PowerShell; however, I can port from many languages, c, c++, c#, pascal, java script, vbscript, etc.  Pseudo code is just as good as real code to me.

Thanks!

Comment: "[...] it breaks the application that uses the info." - sounds like you should ask the authors of the application to stop using duplicate keys in their JSON schema

Comment: The JSON spec explicitly calls out this construct and warns against it, as it observes that parsers behave differently when confronted with duplicate keys (including the behavior that PowerShell exhibits, which is to keep only the last value). You can't really expect other languages and libraries to handle this in a roundtrip manner either, it'd be the luck of the draw. See if the authors can be persuaded to also allow a string array in `_Comment`, that roundtrips easily while still being readable.

Comment: The vendor not going to change it...  They consider it a "Feature" to allow humans to edit it easier.  I ended up writing my own parser.  It was faster than stripping out the _Comment and _Comments lines and putting them back before saving.